# how can I insert a delimiter two places after each decimal in a line of text

Tags: python-3.x, split

Noob here... I'm learning python and trying to slice a line of text to insert ',' a delimiter. I can't seem to find each decimal to insert a delimiter two places over. I can do it on the first decimal but not the rest of them. Any help is appreciated.

I want:
4743 i03/2064.03,4764 i03/2021.30,4745*i03/29111.85,4765 i03/2592.50

```
line = '4743 i03/2064.034764 i03/2021.304745*i03/29111.854765 i03/2592.50'
index = line.find('.')
output_line = line[:index+3] + ',' + line[index+3:]
print( output_line )
```

Comment: Do you want to replace every '.' with ','?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to add a delimiter 2 places after the '.' So instead of: 4743 i03/2064.034764 I want: 4743 i03/2064.03,4764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using Regular-expression:

```
import re
line = '4743 i03/2064.034764 i03/2021.304745*i03/29111.854765 i03/2592.50'
line = re.sub(r'(\..{2})', r'\1,', line)
print(line)
```

Output:

```
4743 i03/2064.03,4764 i03/2021.30,4745*i03/29111.85,4765 i03/2592.50,
```

However, notice that the last grouping will also return `.50,` because it will still match the given rules in your question.

You can read up on Regular-expression [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

---

Let's break down what is happening inside of the `re.sub` function.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for the command, we can see that it has the following parameters:

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

Let's look at our pattern:

`r'(\..{2})'`

Firstly, we set the string into a `raw` string by adding the prefix `r` before we create it. You can read up on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). The short version: It tells us that characters like `\` should be interpreted as a literal backslash.

We then create a `capture-group` by surrounding our pattern with `()`. After which we `escape` the `.` with a backslash, because in regular-expression `.` matches against all characters (if you use the correct flags).

So, now we have this `r'(\.)'` which matches against a literal `.` in the string. However, we also want to match against two trailing characters afterwards.

We do this by using the `.` that we mentioned earlier matches against all characters, however we tell it to match two characters by adding the suffix `{2}` after the dot.

Now we have the full pattern: `r'(\..{2})'`

Now we want to use that pattern, and replace it for something else.

We do this with the replacement-pattern: `r'\1,'`

`\1` here is a back-reference to the capture-group that we created earlier, and contains a literal dot, followed by two characters. After we call back that matching string, we then append a `,` after it.

Finally, we tell the `re.sub` command to take `line` as the input-string for the command.

---

There are lots of resources online where you can learn Regular-Expression. If you would like to experiment with the above pattern, I have created a link for you [here](https://regexr.com/52pck) where you can get a better hang on it.

Comment: This works great and I can always chop off that last ','. Thank you! Now I just have to figure out what the code is doing... lol

Comment: Alright cool! I'll edit the answer to include a little more explanation for what is happening!

Comment: @Alis I've added a wall of text to try to explain what is happening. Feel free to add another comment if you would like some further information.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was making it so much harder. I will dive into re.sub() to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace every `.` with `,` try this:

```py
line = '4743 i03/2064.034764 i03/2021.304745*i03/29111.854765 i03/2592.50'
output_line = line.replace(".", ",")
print(output_line)
```

The [`.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method with two argument there replaces every occurance of the first argument with the second (in this case, it swaps the `.` with `,`).